# Has there been evidence that there has been coevolution in E. Coli strains with the T4 bacteriophage?

Tags: evolution, microbiology, bacteriology, virology, bacteriophage

According to [Evolution of T4-related phages](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/8828153/), there have been multiple instances of evolution in the T4 coliphages. Per the article, there are many T-even phages that have insertions from other coliphages. Per [Oechslin's paper](https://www.mdpi.com/1999-4915/10/7/351), different bacteriophages have different effects with different strains of *E. Coli*. Has there been evidence that there has been coevolution in *E. Coli* strains with the T4 bacteriophage? I have found a paper on the coevolution of *E. Coli* and PP01 at [Coevolution of bacteriophage PP01 and *Escherichia coli* O157:H7 in continuous culture](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/12513992/). Still, I have not found any information regarding T4 coliphages and their coevolution with *E. Coli*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

High-level answer: Yes. Almost by definition there might have to be coevolution between a phage and a host, in the same way that humans coevolve with our viruses (in the form of e.g. immune repertoire). Pathogens kill/disadvantage susceptible hosts, imposing a selective cost to susceptibility.

Detailed answer: Yes. E. coli [has CRISPR arrays that target T4](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0098811), and [T4 has mechanisms for escaping CRISPR processing by E. coli](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/34154416/). This is pretty textbook [coevolutionary arms race](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_arms_race). This is reflected somewhat [in the different host ranges of phage](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC532421/), as you suggest.